# Cannot set output_style for libsass using python to compile SASS on each deploy

Tags: python, css, sass, setup.py, libsass

Here is a documentation on how to compile SASS to CSS via python including the possibility to set `output_style='compressed'`:
https://sass.github.io/libsass-python/

```py
import sass
sass.compile(dirname=('sass', 'css'), output_style='compressed')
```

Here is how to do it on each deploymant which is exactly what I need:
https://sass.github.io/libsass-python/frameworks/flask.html#building-sass-scss-for-each-deployment

```py
# setyp.py

setup(
    # ...,
    setup_requires=['libsass >= 0.6.0'],
    sass_manifests={
        'myapp': ('static/sass', 'static/css', '/static/css')
    }
)
```

However, I need to set the `output_style` while compiling SASS on each deploy the way how it is described on the second page and I cannot figure out how to do it. Is there any way to do it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found a solution**

change the `setup.cfg` as follows:

```
[aliases]
sdist = build_sass --output-style compressed sdist
bdist = build_sass --output-style compressed bdist
```

insted of

```
[aliases]
sdist = build_sass sdist
bdist = build_sass bdist
```